# File Encryption

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'n written this small file encryption module to work on my skills with the `os` module. It's my very first time using it to navigate files and file structures, so I'm sure some things can be improved. I used the following file structure to ensure it works with multiple directories:

## File Structure

```
.
├── files
│   ├── files
│   │   ├── test.txt
│   │   ├── test2.txt
│   │   └── test3.txt
│   ├── files2
│   │   ├── files
│   │   │   ├── test.txt
│   │   │   ├── test2.txt
│   │   │   └── test3.txt
│   │   ├── test.txt
│   │   ├── test2.txt
│   │   └── test3.txt
│   ├── test.txt
│   ├── test2.txt
│   └── test3.txt
├── key.py
└── virus.py
```

It works flawlessly. I'm looking for feedback on a couple topics:

1. **`os` module**: Are there other functions in the `os` module that could be used to accomplish the same thing, but easier or faster?
2. **file management**: Is there a faster way to work with files than I did? The time it takes is noticeable ( 0s < time < 1s for a file of ~2500 characters) but I'm sure it gets longer with bigger files.

```
"""
File Encryption & Decryption
"""

import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

from key import KEY

DIRECTORY = "files"
FERNET = Fernet(KEY)

def crypt(encrypt=True) -> None:
    """
    Encrypts/Decrypts the files in DIRECTORY
    """

    for root, _, files in os.walk(DIRECTORY, topdown=True):
        for name in files:
            file = os.path.join(root, name)

            with open(file, "rb") as in_file:
                data = in_file.read()

            data = FERNET.encrypt(data) if encrypt else FERNET.decrypt(data)

            with open(file, "wb") as out_file:
                out_file.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Encrypt #
    crypt()

    # Decrypt #
    crypt(encrypt=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Boolean arguments are a code smell. Especially in a case like this you'd want to have separate `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions, which both reuse a third function which does all the bookkeeping. In this case the third function could just take the `FERNET.encrypt` or `FERNET.decrypt` method as an argument, and apply it to the data.
2. For this to be generally usable you'll want to add some argument parsing, possibly with `argparse`, to be able to pass an arbitrary path to work with.
3. The key should not be in code - it's just data, and should be stored in the original key format. If it's just a /dev/urandom dump with no structure to it that would be a .bin format, but I'm not familiar with Fernet. The code would normally be told about the key by passing a path argument or by passing the contents on standard input.

Generally I wouldn't worry about encryption and decryption taking a long time. If your key is too long (algorithm-specific) it could slow down the algorithm considerably, but many algorithms can be considered quite slow with common inputs. I don't know why you chose Fernet specifically, but there are many algorithms available, and you might want to evaluate them for strength and speed.